# How to extract contents of a table from webpage using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need help in extracting kmz and zip files from a webpage. The following code is able to extract the table, but not the files and links inside the table. What can I include in my code so that the output table also contains the links and files instead of just plain text?

Webpage:

```
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/'
result = pd.read_html(url)[0]
result
```

Comment: You would like to download the files?

Comment: Yes, I want to download these files.

Comment: The output should be a table using which I can download these files. Meaning, the links on the actual webpage table should be working on the output table as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use beautifulsoup to get all the links.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table")
for anchor in table.find_all("a"):
    print("Text - {}, Link - {}".format(anchor.get_text(strip=True), anchor["href"]))
```

Output:

```
Text - Irma Example, Link - /gis/examples/al112017_5day_020.zip
Text - Cone, Link - /gis/examples/AL112017_020adv_CONE.kmz
Text - Track, Link - /gis/examples/AL112017_020adv_TRACK.kmz
Text - Warnings, Link - /gis/examples/AL112017_020adv_WW.kmz
Text - shp, Link - forecast/archive/al092020_5day_latest.zip
Text - Cone, Link - /storm_graphics/api/AL092020_CONE_latest.kmz
Text - Track, Link - /storm_graphics/api/AL092020_TRACK_latest.kmz
Text - Warnings, Link - /storm_graphics/api/AL092020_WW_latest.kmz
```

If you want to retain the dataframe, don't make a network call again via `read_html`. Reuse the response object.

```
df = pd.read_html(res.text)
```

To get the complete link, append the following to all the links.

```
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov
```

Code:

```
for anchor in table.find_all("a"):
    print("Text - {}, Link - {}".format(anchor.get_text(strip=True), prefix + anchor["href"]))
```

Output:

```
Text - Irma Example, Link - https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/al112017_5day_020.zip
Text - Cone, Link - https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/AL112017_020adv_CONE.kmz
Text - Track, Link - https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/AL112017_020adv_TRACK.kmz
Text - Warnings, Link - https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/examples/AL112017_020adv_WW.kmz
Text - shp, Link - https://www.nhc.noaa.govforecast/archive/al092020_5day_latest.zip
Text - Cone, Link - https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL092020_CONE_latest.kmz
Text - Track, Link - https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL092020_TRACK_latest.kmz
Text - Warnings, Link - https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL092020_WW_latest.kmz
```

To download the files, again use `requests` and download the file

Comment: bs4 is not working for our table. As you can see, your code is giving 8 files as output. But, there are more than 8 files in the table.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say use beautifulsoup (bs4) instead of pandas to parse html.

```
pip install beautifulsoup4 requests
```

and then it's as simple as

```
import bs4
import requests

result = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/').content, features='html.parser')
for link in result.find('table').find_all('a'):
    print(link.attrs['href'])
```

Comment: I don't know why but it seems that beautifulsoup is not working for this webpage. Moreover, I need the output in the form of a table.